# HTML5 internationalization language

Tags: html, internationalization, browser

I'm reading about different options to internationalizate a simple web page.
In the documentation I founded articles like: [How to Localize HTML5 Projects](http://www.ab-weblog.com/en/internationalization-how-to-localize-html5-projects/) but always uses Passive localization in JavaScript.
Exist a clean way to implement internationalisation language without use it, or exist an web browser standard to implement it?

Reference: https://blog.mozilla.org/l10n/category/internationalization/

Comment: The question is both too vague and too broad, and it asks about “HTML5 internationalization language” without saying what is meant by that.

Comment: If you're asking how you can do it without Javascript, the answer is to use the server side language, obviously. But without specifying what you're after precisely, all you're going to get is links to articles you've read already.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "passive localization". Regardless of what you mean by that, I strongly suggest using server-side localization. Server-side is a place where you know the contents of HTTP Accept-Language header, so it is relatively easy to deal with translations. BTW. Many web servers are capable of serving different language versions of a web site...